# Django: When saving input from drop down lists, saves option value instead of actual value

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

to preface my question I would like to say I'm pretty new to Django, so be gentle. Thanks in advance!

I have two drop down boxes, All_team_Form and Product_Form (both ModelChoiceField).

```
class All_team_Form(forms.ModelForm):
   teams = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= All_teams.objects.all().order_by('team_name'))

   class Meta:
       model = All_teams
       fields = ('team_name', 'team_type')
       widgets = {'team_name': HiddenInput(),'team_type': HiddenInput()}


class Product_Form(forms.ModelForm):
   products = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Product.objects.all().order_by('product'))

   class Meta:
       model = Product
       fields = ('product',)
       widgets = {'product': HiddenInput(),}
```

The way I'm saving the POSTED input is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    pattern = request.POST.get('pattern')
    team = request.POST.get('teams')
    product = request.POST.get('products')
    pub_date = timezone.now()
    team_obj = Sys_team(pattern=pattern, sys_team=team, product=product, pub_date= pub_date, alert= "[CPU]")
    team_obj.save()


context = {

'all_form' : All_team_Form(),
'product_form' : Product_Form()

}

return render(request, 'test4.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<td>              
{% for a in all_form %}
   {{a}} 
{% endfor %}
</td>
```

The current problem I'm encountering is that when it is saving the Sys_team object, it gets what I assume is the default option value for all_form, which are numbers. when I print out all_form in the python shell, it displays a list in the format of: `<option value="4">thestuffIwant</option>`

A lot of the documentation I've read says I should include `<option value = {{ a }}>{{a}}</option>`. However, when I try that it messes up the drop down lists by adding a normal list of all the options in the drop down list above it. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, yes.  Django's form will return the `value` associated with the object.  You can use get the associated object you want by doing `All_teams.objects.get(pk=team)`.  Your code has lots wrong with it from a canonical Django perspective.  You should validate your form first - `if request.method == 'POST' and all_form.is_valid():` after assigning the form to the `all_form` variable.  I got the sense that you're trying to use the rest of Django without using the  coupling between Django's models and forms.  You should use forms in views as well as in templates.  It'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem. I just added an additional argument to my ModelForm queryset.

`teams = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= All_teams.objects.all().order_by('team_name'), to_field_name="team_name")`

I only used forms to load the drop down list and decided against using forms to save the data because I wasn't saving the user input to a form. I had multiple drop down lists (all different forms) and other user input that I wanted to save to one of my models. It is easier and probably more efficient just to use request.POST.get('xxxx') than to declare each respective form model.

Answer (score 0):

You must validate your form first and use form.cleaned_data instead of request.POST.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    all_form = All_team_Form(request.POST)
    product_form = Product_Form(request.POST)
    if all_form.is_valid() and product_form.is_valid():
        pattern = request.POST.get('pattern')
        team = all_form.cleaned_data.get('teams')
        product = product_form.cleaned_data.get('products')
        pub_date = timezone.now()
        team_obj = Sys_team(pattern=pattern, sys_team=team, product=product, pub_date= pub_date, alert= "[CPU]")
        team_obj.save()
else:
    all_form = All_team_Form()
    product_form = Product_Form()

context = {

'all_form' : all_form,
'product_form' : product_form,

}

return render(request, 'test4.html', context)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on what is getting passed when I initialize the all_form variable (all_form = All_team_Form(request.POST)). I keep getting false when running the is_valid method, even when I hard code the team field within the python shell